# Removing files with Build Phase?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, shell, xcode4

Is it possible to remove a file using a build phase in xcode 4 based on if it is release or dev?

If so has anyone got an example?

I have tried :

```
      if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]; then
      find "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR" -name '*-live.*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
      fi
```

This prints CopyStringsFile

```
 "build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Blue Sky.app/PortalText-live.strings" CDL/PortalText-live.strings
cd "/Users/internet/Desktop/iPhone Template/iPhonePortalTemplate/CDL.Labs"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copyStrings --validate --inputencoding utf-8 --outputencoding binary --outdir "/Users/internet/Desktop/iPhone Template/iPhonePortalTemplate/CDL.Labs/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Blue Sky.app" -- CDL/PortalText-live.strings
```

But does actually remove the file from the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've ever had different files, is having a separate Target, and only include certain files in certain targets.

EDIT WITH AN EXAMPLE

Ok, I've done exactly the same in another project. We had a DefaultProperties.plist file, which was included in the target.

We then had 3 copies of this, NOT included in the target, ProdProperties.plist, TestProperties.plist, UatProperties.plist.

We built for environments on the command line, using xcodebuild, as it was built using an automated build server (Bamboo).

Prior to executing xcodebuild, we would run this:

```
cp -vf "./Properties/Environments/${environment}Properties.plist" ./Properties/shared/DefaultProperties.plist
touch Properties/shared/DefaultProperties.plist
```

with $(environment) being passed into the script.

You could do something like this with the RunScript phase in Xcode.

Comment: The reason for me for having two different files is I make calls to a webservice and there is a dev version and a live version so I have what I have call a backoffice-dev/live.xml file that handles all the urls and other configuration requirements for the different versions I have my code select the right file in the appdelegate.m but there is no point having the extra file in there so want to remove in a build phase, its not that important so if it can't be done then so be it. I just thought i would ask.